# Why can I upload files to Wasabi using S3 and Laravel, but trying to get returns file not found?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, wasabi-hot-cloud-storage

So I am using Wasabi for object storage in my Laravel API, but after I got the upload working, now I can't get the download to work.

I am using this package: https://github.com/ProbablyRational/wasabi-storage, instead of the flysystem-s3 package (although it uses it internally anyway).

This is how I upload my files (only the relevant part):

```
$fileName = uniqid(). '.' . File::extension($file->getClientOriginalName());

Storage::disk('s3')->put('/tracks/' . $fileName, $file->getContent());


$track = Track::create(array_merge($request->all(), ['file' => $fileName]));

return response()->json($track, 201);
```

This works and I can see the files in my Wasabi bucket.
But when trying to get the file:

```
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse(
        Storage::disk('s3')->get(json_encode('tracks/' . $track->file))
    );
    BinaryFileResponse::trustXSendfileTypeHeader();
    $headers = 'Content-Type: audio/mpeg';
    $response.header($headers);
```

This returns "File not found at path: "tracks/62751e3730359.wav"", even though the file is uploaded.

Comment: You have a slash on the put, and no slash on the get, in front of tracks. Try adding the slash?

Comment: @aynber Good spot, but not the problem...

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "the file is uploaded", you mean you've confirmed this by actually seeing this file in Wasabi, right, and not just trusting that the upload worked? Can you download from the file from Wasabi directly, just to make sure that's working?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yep, I can list all the files and it will be there. I can also download it.